# How do I remove Ubuntu from windows?

Tags: wubi, uninstall

I installed the Ubuntu for Windows version on my vista and it crashed after updating. I tried first to delete it like any other regular app (because that with Ubuntu claims you could), but that didn't work.

Next, I tried to repair my mbr, but that didn't work. It still shows Ubuntu as a second choice OS for booting up. What can I do?

- This is not a regular dual boot system.

Comment: what dual boot system is it then?

Comment: It sounds like you did a WUBI install, if this is correct then the uninstall guide is at the bottom of [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi). If this doesn't help, please edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and customize your boot option! It's very easy.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use EasyBCD to remove the listing in Bootmenue, but you also have to delete Linux Partitions.
Just use Gparted LiveCD to delete these partitions. It is also very easy.